# cassandra's write operations sequencial. why it does not have issue?

Tags: cassandra

This is as per the official documentation.

```
All writes are sequential, which is the primary reason that writes perform so well in
Cassandra. No reads or seeks of any kind are required for writing a value to Cassandra
because all writes are append operations.
```

am confused because in case there is insert operation and duplicate primary key case, cassandra will require the search first from memtable or in case if data is flushed to sstable.

so if user id with value 123 is already present and we are inserting row with 123, it fails because internally it does read based on that key. this is the doubt i have if someone can clarify pls.

Answer (score 2):

There is no notion of duplicate keys in Cassandra. Every change written to Cassandra has a timestamp and Cassandra does timestamp resolution meaning the data with the latest timestamp always wins and returned. In read path, the content of the key from SSTable is merged with the content of the same key in memtable if exists and the data with latest timestamp is returned. It is worth nothing that each column has a timestamp.

In example:

Let's assume at time 139106495223456 you write the following:

```
123 => {column1:foo column1_timstamp:139106495223456}
```

Then after few microseconds (139106495223470) you write to the same key:

```
123 => {column1:bar column1_timstamp:139106495223470}
```

Both operations will succeed. When you try to read the kay the one with column1:bar is returned because it has the latest timestamp.

Now you may wonder how this works with deletes. Deletes are written the same way except the column/key which is being deleted will be marked with tombstone. If the tombstone has laster timestamp, the row or column will be considered deleted.

You may wonder how this plays with sequential writes to disk as these tombstones or old columns will consume space. It is true. That is why compaction exists and it takes care of compacting and removing expired tomstones.

You can read more about Cassandra write/read path here:

http://www.planetcassandra.org/blog/category/Cassandra%20read%20path
http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.1/dml/about_writes